# What is the method to permanently enable SMB v1 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

What is the method to permanently enable SMB v1 on Windows 10?

Historically we have been using the `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName smb1protocol` PowerShell command to re-enable SMB v1 however recently we are seeing computers not be able to map drives that are being served from older Linux servers as it seems that Windows is disabling it at random intervals (some appear to be when the computer has been restarted or has been sleeping).

Comment: Enabling SMBv1 is a large security hole and Permanent (forever) is a long time. Feature updates continue to disable SMBv1 as far as I know. Fix / replace the devices that need SMBv1.

Comment: MS SMBv1 Announcements --- [Stop using SMB1 - First published on TECHNET on Sep 16, 2016](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/stop-using-smb1/ba-p/425858) --- [Microsoft to Disable SMBv1 in Windows Starting This Fall 2017](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-to-disable-smbv1-in-windows-starting-this-fall) --- [SMBv1 is not installed by default in Windows 10 version 1709, Windows Server version 1709 and later versions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/smbv1-not-installed-by-default-in-windows)

Comment: A work around is to write a script that will determine if the feature is enable or disabled, if it's disabled then it will be installed and a reboot will be performed, if it's enabled it will do nothing.  You can run this script when the user logs into their account.  However, this is a huge security risk, you really should configure your Linux servers to use SMBv3

Comment: @Ramhound We have machinery with embedded computers that are Windows XP (and older) that also need to map the drives so I do not believe that is an option.